# Multiplication of invertible matrix and its inverse and an arbitrary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $B$ an arbitrary matrix in $\mathbb{R}^3$, and $T$ an invertible Matrix also in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let $ C = T^{-1}BT$

What can be said about the eigenvalues of $C$, given the eigenvalues and eigenvector of $B$?

Comment: $B$ and $C$ represent the same linear operator. Therefore...?

Comment: Something very easy, but my mind is blocked. A little bit more hint, please..

Comment: Btw, [normal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_matrix) has a specific meaning, and is not synonymous with "generic".

Comment: Wait. Eigenvectors of an operator represent the vectors that remain the same under the operator. So eigenvectors are the same.

Comment: no, i mean *any* matrix, $B$...

Comment: The eigen*values* are the same. The eigenvectors are related by a change of basis.

Comment: aH, okey. Thanks.